# Add panel dynamically

Tags: java, jpanel, swingx

I have in my form `JList` component,  and I want when user select item from `JList` to add a new panel on existing `JLayeredPanel` with item's name. There is my panel:

```
package forme;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */

public class PanelProcesses extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
 * Creates new form PanelProcesses
 */
public PanelProcesses() {
    initComponents();
}

PanelProcesses(String name) {
    initComponents();
    jlbProcess.setText(name);
}                    
}
```

And there is method in main form when user click on item in `JList`:

```
 private void jlProcessesMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

     Process p = (Process) jlProcesses.getSelectedValue();
    System.out.println(p.getName());
    PanelProcesses pp = new PanelProcesses(p.getName());
    pp.setOpaque(true);
   // pp.setVisible(true);
    jlpProcesses.add(pp);
    jlpProcesses.repaint();
    jlpProcesses.setVisible(true);
    //this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Problem is when I click on item panel is not attached to `JLayeredPanel` (jlpProcesses). Does someone know where I make mistake? Through debug mode I see that new instance op `PanelProcess` is made and attribute visible is true.

Comment: use jlpProcesses.revalidate()

Comment: JList with variable name jlProcess

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) where is the 'SwingX'?

Comment: If your using a JLayerdPane, you would normally be resources to provide both location size of the components you add to it, unless you've set a layout manager to the panel of course

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with setting BoxLayout, and then Java puts automatically new panel below others.